# if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }[\alpha a_{n}+\beta b_{n}]$ exist then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}$ too?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

"Let $\alpha ,\beta \in (0,1),\alpha +\beta =1,\{a_{n}\}$ and $\ \{b_{n}\}$
real, nonnegative, bounded sequences. If
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }[\alpha  a_{n}+\beta b_{n}]\text{ exist }
\end{equation*}

then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}b_{n}$ exist?"

cannot prove it  or cannot give counterexample please help me

Comment: How are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ quantified?  Is it for all $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: I think $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are supposed to be constants...?

Comment: yes they are constant

Comment: $$\frac12\cos^2n+\frac12\sin^2n$$

Comment: Given  divergent sequence a and alpha=beta=.5 choose b=-a .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a simple counterexample, consider some $0\le b_n=1-a_n\le1$ known to have no limit vs. $\frac12a_n+\frac12b_n$. (Could be $a_n=\sin^2n$.)

Comment: "$\alpha,\beta \in (0,1)$"

Comment: @gt6989b Fixed.

Comment: upvoted already